# Create a plot between the proportion of two variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

From a set of two variables:

```
df <- data.frame(stock = c("stockA", "StockA", "StockA", "StockB", "StockB"), name = c("Julia", "Julia", "Python", "Python", "Python")
```

How is it possible to produce a dataframe like this:

```
dfvalues <- data.frame(stock = c("StockA", "StockA", "StockB"), name = c("Julia", "Python", "Python"), value  = c(2,1,2))
```

and create a plot like this where instead of years have the stock and instead of the volume of countries have the names such as [this](https://socviz.co/dataviz-pdfl_files/figure-html4/ch-06-dodgeplot-1.png) plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in your code creating df data frame. First value of stock columns start with lowercase. I am not sure if that was done on purpose or not so I will assume it was a typo.

So to answer your question:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(stock, name) %>% 
  summarise(value = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  stock  name   value
  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1 StockA Julia      2
2 StockA Python     1
3 StockB Python     2
```

Now, I'm not sure if `geom_errorbar` would be the best idea to represent your data. Especially that you df lack `ymin` and `ymax` values. However if you can live without this vertical line making a `geom_point` chart would take you there:

```
 ggplot(dfvalues , aes(stock, value, col = name))+
    geom_point(size = 5)+
    theme(legend.position="top")
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]